# Help with the proof of the Witch of Agnesi curve

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry, trigonometry

$a=1$ (The radius is 1).
How do I prove that if we talking about $P=(x,y)$, then:  $$y=\frac{8}{x^2+4}$$
I'd like to get any help!

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: You already asked about this a few hours ago and you were shown that the parametrics of the curve are

$$x=2a\cot t\;,\;\;y=2a\sin^2t\implies\;\text{with $\;a=1\;$ we have:}$$

$$x^2+4=4\cot^2t+4=4\left(1+\frac{\cos^2t}{\sin^2t}\right)=\frac4{\sin^2t} \implies$$

$$\implies\frac8{x^2+4}=2\sin^2t=y$$

Did you **really** need to ask this question?

Comment: Hey Don! Yes because I tried few times but I didn't succeed..:-(

Comment: @DonAntonio, why you began with $x^2+4$?

Comment: Because I know where to go, @Yoav. You are asked to *prove* that relation, not to invent it.

Comment: Oh! I see!! Thank you @DonAntonio! it's the simplest prove here! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line through $O$ and $A$ has equation $x=\frac{x_A}{2}y$, the circle has equation $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$. Substituting $x$ from the first into the second you find the coordinates $(x_B,y_B)$ of $B$. You get $(\frac{x_A}{2}y_B)^2+(y_B-1)^2=1$ whence $((4+x_A^2)y_B-8)y_B=0$. Noting that $y_P=y_B$ and $x_P=x_A$ you finally get $((4+x_P^2)y_B-8)y_P=0$.

Comment: What do you mean when you write: "Substituting $x$ from the first into the second"?

Comment: @Yoav Fridman Edited. Is it clear now?

Comment: Alex, but how it's describe the coordinates of $P$? i.e. x,y should be the coordinates of $P$.

Comment: @Yoav Fridman $y_B=y_P$, $x_A=x_P$.

Comment: Oh...So $y$ is $y_B$? I'm right?

Comment: About $x$ did you mean $x_A=\frac{x_A}{2}y$?

Comment: Of course not, 'cause then it would be $y=2$. $x$ and $y$ here are the coordinates on the line through $O$ and $A$.

Comment: And yes, if you call $y$ the ordinate of $P$, then in the final equation $y=y_B$.

Comment: alex, how do you get this: $((4+x_A^2)y_B-8)y_B=0$?

Comment: @Yoar Just expand the previous equation and gather $y_B$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$x_B^2=1-(1-y_B)^2$,

$x_A=x_P=x$,

$y_B=y_P=y$ and $$\frac{x_A}{y_A}=\frac{x_B}{y_B}$$

Comment: And how I continue from there? Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman, After substitution in fractions and squaring we have $$\frac{x^2}{4}=\frac{1-(1-y)^2}{y^2}=-1+\frac{2}{y}$$ and it gives us $$y=\frac{8}{x^2+4}$$

Comment: How do you get the first line: $\frac{x^2}{4}=\frac{1-(1-y)^2}{y^2}=-1+\frac{2}{y}$?

Comment: @YoavFridman, $x_A=x_P=x$, $y_A=2$, $x_B=(1-(1-y)^2)^{1/2}$, and $y_B=y_P=y$.